# Navbar class is not active on click using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to active nav-bar menu when clicked from nav bar, i am using the following code, to active nav menu when clicked, but it is not working for me.
i am using bootstrap classes for add nav-bar into  my webpage.
please help me to find where i am mistaken?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".mr-auto .nav-item").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedItem = $(this);
    $(".mr-auto .nav-item").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    clickedItem.addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header" class="header header1">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
      <img src="images/site-logo.png" alt="Site-logo">
    </a>
    <div id="toggle-icon" class="icon-btn">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-nav" class="navigation-menu">
      <div class="navbar-collap" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="careers">Careers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item contact-link">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact-us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="button">
          <a class="btn btn1" id="cont" href="contact.php">contact us <i class="icon-feature-6"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you with not working? when you click on a link the js add the class to the element

Comment: You code work just fine when I run it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen but when i run it, it does not reflect any active menu.

Comment: @ParteekKumar So when you inspect the code it can't see the active class on any of them?`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No i did not saw any active class, i found my element select on clicked is not accurate set.

Comment: @ParteekKumar Do you get any error in your code?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i Found no error, it's working now, but when i clicked on menu, its active but again deactive after page refreshed.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen   ```$(".navbar-nav .nav-link").on("click", function(){
        $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });```

Comment: @ParteekKumar Of course it does not stay active after page refresh.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen
```
$.each($('#navbar').find('li'), function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active',
            window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).find('a').attr('href')) > -1);
    });
```
This code working fine, but not with index.php page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233871/discussion-between-parteek-kumar-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).

Answer (score 0):

The .active class  does not highlight the nav-link.

**Solution 1**

add css:

```
.mr-auto .nav-item.active a{background: blue;color:#fff}
```

**Solution 2**

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".mr-auto .nav-item a").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedItem = $(this);
    
  $(".mr-auto .nav-item a.active").removeClass("active btn-primary");

    clickedItem.addClass("active btn-primary");
  });
});
```